# Способы просмотра БД на андроид студио

Tags: android, sqlite

Какие есть способы просмотра бд на андроид студио?
На англоязычном stackoverflow есть [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-to-view-the-sqlite-database-in-device-android), но может быть появились новые, более простые способы за 2 года?

Comment: Нет, не появились

Comment: да был такой, вопрос 1 в 1